# How to create a new transaction when @NoTransaction is used?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, playframework, playframework-1.x

```
@NoTransaction
public static void myAction() {
  // Can I do anything here to start a transaction myself?
}
```

One workaround I thought about is creating a job. Is there another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at JPAPlugin.startTx(readOnly) - perhaps you can use it directly or take the code from it.  But it does make me wonder why you want to do this?

I think creating a Job sounds like a better idea.

Comment: Just for a status check page, nothing more. I'll just use a job.